# chroot-like environment in Java?

Tags: java, security

For certain not-that-much-trusted libraries, I'd like to limit access to the filesystem and network.

I know about Java security policies in `security.policy`. But that limits methods calls.
What I need is some kind of internal firewall and ACL.

It can be as simple as limiting filesystem access to some subtree, and limiting network access to a particular IP(s).

Is there something like that on Java level, or do I have to do it on the system level?

Comment: I don't believe so. The only program I know of that does something like that is the Game Robocode, but that requires them to use its custom file access.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to implement a "sandbox" for untrusted code using a classloader with a security manager configured with a custom security policy.  That's how the Java browser plugin  stops untrusted applets from connecting to random websites or reading / writing files in the host filesystem.

However, it is not clear how it is feasible to implement ACL-based filesystem access this way.  That would most likely require writing a custom SecurityManager class.

I'd *first* look at how easy it is to do using system level facilities.

Comment: Thanks. It may be easy at system level, but that puts the burden of doing it at user. I'd like to allow certain tools to handle this out of the box.

Comment: *"... but that puts the burden of doing it at user"*.  Not necessarily.  It depends if you could script the set-up.